# Can a U.S. President pardon an accessory to murder if the murder occurred in a foreign country?

Tags: pardon

If a U.S. citizen conspires to have another U.S. citizen murdered but the actual killing takes place in a foreign country, can the accessory to the murder be pardoned by the President?

Comment: If the person is being charged under foreign law, the President has no power to pardon that person under those laws.

Comment: @RonBeyer as the answer below indicates, the same is true if the person is being charged under US state law.  Jon Allen: welcome to the site, please accept the answer by clicking the check mark below the voting buttons.

Answer (score 17):

He can, to the extent that there is a federal charge involved. There is no limit to the power to "grant reprieves and pardons for offenses against the United States", but there is no power to grant reprieve or pardon against a US state or foreign country.

In other words, a presidential pardon would prevent the person from being tried or punished by the US federal government. It would not prevent them from being tried or punished by a state or foreign government.

Comment: In other words, a presidential pardon would prevent the person from being tried or punished by the US federal government.  It would not prevent them from being tried or punished by a state or foreign government.